# Android: is Cursor.getColumnIndex() invariant over row loop?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

It seems like `android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndex(String)` should be invariant over the row loop.

Yet I see loads of code doing stuff like:

```
try (Cursor cursor = database.query(...)) {
  while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String aString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(aColumnName));
    // ... other loop code and more repeated use of getColumnIndex()
  }
}
```

This seems silly and wasteful unless the result of `getColumnIndex()` can really vary with calls to `cursor.moveToNext()` -- and that this call should be hoisted out of the loop like:

```
try (Cursor cursor = database.query(...)) {
  int aStringIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(aColumnName);
  while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String aString = cursor.getString(aStringIdx);
    // ... other loop code
  }
}
```

or in the worst case (assuming `getColumnIndex()` requires that you be on a valid data row):

```
try (Cursor cursor = database.query(...)) {
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int aStringIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(aColumnName);
    do {
      String aString = cursor.getString(aStringIdx);
      // ... other loop code
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
}
```

So what's the real story here?

Comment: [Sturgeon's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon's_law).

Comment: The right answer must be related to SQLiteCursor (getColumnIndex() optimized) not AbstractCursor !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was seeing all did getColumnIndex each time through the row loop, which made no sense at all

Maybe is because when we execute a query we receive an [**SQLiteCursor**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java#SQLiteCursor) instance, not an AbstractCursor. If we look at source code we can find that internally a chache is built:

```
  @Override
    public int getColumnIndex(String columnName) {
        // Create mColumnNameMap on demand
        if (mColumnNameMap == null) {
            String[] columns = mColumns;
            int columnCount = columns.length;
            HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(columnCount, 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                map.put(columns[i], i);
            }
            mColumnNameMap = map;
        }

       //...
    }
```

On the other hand, accesing a variable (like your example 2) is faster than calculating hash key to get the index. Could be relevent depending on the size of the table.

***Edit: testing on a large table with complex queries, seems that the improvement aproaches the 5%, in my case is not worth making the change. In general, that HashMap caching is good enough.***

Answer (score 1):

There is **no dependency** between `getColumnIndex()` and `moveToNext()` methods.(Option number two of yours will be the best approach)
You can see this by looking at the [Cursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) interface implementation in [AbstractCursor](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/AbstractCursor.java) under the [moveToPosition()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/AbstractCursor.java#304) and [getColumnIndex()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/AbstractCursor.java#304) methods source.

Comment: Thanks that certainly seemed to be the case, but the code samples I was seeing all did getColumnIndex each time through the row loop, which made no sense at all.

I'm actually tending towards option 3 above -- since getColumnIndex is a linear search on the column names and though option 3 is a bit uglier it only looks up column indexes when there is data to process.